# Why can't those two jquery functions work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote those 2 simple scrolling functions

```
$(".scrollTo").click(function() {
    var t = $(this).attr("href");
    return $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(t).offset().top - 100
    }, {
        duration: 1e3,
        easing: "easeInOutQuint"
    })
});

$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
    return $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, {
        duration: 1e3,
        easing: "easeInOutQuint"
    })
});
```

But the second one will never work unless I delete the first one.. I'm new at js and I don't understand why those 2 functions cant work at the same time ? I tried several syntax tricks but none of them worked unfortunately

Comment: Does `a[href='#top']` also have the class `.scrollTo`?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What are you expecting to happen?  What actually happens?  When you debug this, where does it seem to fail?

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: damn george is right, it was a markup problem, the href=#top did have a scrollTo class .. I'm ashamed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `return` statements and prevent the default behavior of the anchor. Try this.

```
$(".scrollTo").click(function() {
    var t = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(t).offset().top - 100
    }, {
        duration: 1e3,
        easing: "easeInOutQuint"
    });
});

$("a[href='#top']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, {
        duration: 1e3,
        easing: "easeInOutQuint"
    });
});
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, I think if you get rid of the `return` statement it will probably work. I'd imagine that the return part of your code is doing the equivalent of `stopPropagation()`